# Heroku pandas numpy error "Unable to import required dependencies:\n"

Tags: pandas, numpy, heroku

this is my first time deploying flask app to heroku. I have been working on it all day but getting this error I tried removing requirements adding requirements but nothing seems to work so far.

```
    2020-06-30T12:39:52.622174+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 18, in <module>
2020-06-30T12:39:52.622175+00:00 app[web.1]: import pandas as pd
2020-06-30T12:39:52.622175+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
2020-06-30T12:39:52.622176+00:00 app[web.1]: "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
2020-06-30T12:39:52.622176+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
2020-06-30T12:39:52.622177+00:00 app[web.1]: numpy:
2020-06-30T12:39:52.622177+00:00 app[web.1]: Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
2020-06-30T12:39:52.622178+00:00 app[web.1]: likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
2020-06-30T12:39:52.622178+00:00 app[web.1]: If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
```